# Haskell Parse string of Ints to tuple (Int,Int)

Tags: parsing, haskell, tuples

I would like to parse a string in form 3 3 from input user to a tuple (3,3) is this possible?

```
stringtup :: String -> Maybe (Int, Int)
stringtup s = do
[(n, [c])] <- return $ reads s
return (n, c)
```

this is my attempt but it does't work..

Comment: Of course it is possible, but remember always first add some code showing your attempt and effort, provide more context, (the 3,3 comes from a text file? input from the user?), if you don't, users will downvote the question...

Comment: It's a terminal input, the problem isn't how I get the info.. but rather that I can do it with any String, but if you would like a context I have a command function that take a couple of commands that I'm then callin in my main. And one of my functions need a input (x,y) from the command d 3 3 for example.

Comment: In that case I guess:

"stringtup = (\[a, b] -> (a, b)) . map read . words"

But that throws exception if the format is wrong

Comment: thank you, so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reads` only parses one value (if possible), and gives it back as well as the rest of the *input string*. So,

```
    [(n, _)] <- return $ reads s
```

works and will, for `"3 3"` indeed have `n≡3`.

But the other number still needs to be parsed too. So what you'd actually do is first bind something like

```
    [(n, s')] <- return $ reads s
```

and then parse the other number in the same fashion from `s'`.

Comment: stringtup :: String -> (Int, Int)
stringtup s = do
  [(n, s')] <- return $ reads s
  [(n, _)] <- return $ reads s'
  return (n, s) like this? I get an error saying actual type (Int, (t0, String))

Comment: Similar to that. Provided you properly lay it out in the `do` block. But you need to give both the _parsed_ values as the final result.